# Power Query: How to delete duplicate characters from a string (eg. xzxxxzzzzxzzzzx-> leave only xz)?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a huge table in Power Query with text in cells that consist of multiple 'x's and 'z's. I want to deduplicate values so I have one x and one z only.

For example:

xzzzxxxzxz-> xz

zzzzzzzzzz-> z

The table is very big, so I don't want to create additional columns. Can you please help?

Comment: Hello. Have you tried coming up with any code yourself? If you have something started we can help you, but we can't write it entirely for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to a list of characters, make the list distinct (remove duplicates), sort (if desired), and then transform back to text.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step", {{"ColumnName",
      each Text.Combine( List.Sort( List.Distinct( Text.ToList(_) ) ) ),
      type text}})
```